# Is it possible to refresh fields of a word document with Office.js?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-field

I have word documents with fields that display the value of custom document properties as such:

```
`{ DOCPROPERTY example \* MERGEFORMAT }`
```

Whenever my custom property is modified, in order for the changes to be displayed in my document, I need to select the field(s) and right-click -> update them. I was wondering if office.js had anything that would help me automatically update fields in my document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to do this currently. But it is an excellent idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).