# Is it possible to refresh fields of a document with the Word Javascript API?

Tags: api, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-field

I've foud a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719440/is-it-possible-to-refresh-fields-of-a-word-document-with-office-js) from 2013, but I'm wondering if there is a solution for this now.

I have a word document with fields as such:

```
{ DOCPROPERTY example \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

When my property is modified, in order for the changes to be displayed, I need to select the field(s) and right-click -> update. I am wondering if there is a method in the Word Javascript API to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As Rick suggested in that thread, There is no API to do this currently, Please suggest it on our [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)